# How to select a folder through php and sent path to script

Tags: php, perl, post, path

I'm currently working on a website where the user has to select a folder, which contains a number of data files. The path to this folder then has to be passed to a Perl-script. The script will then run the content of the folder.

The website, files and scripts will all be running on the same server. The user only has to use the web interface to select the folder in which the needed files are present, the path will then be passes to the script. So no uploading is needed, only selecting a folder path...

I hope this explanation is somewhat clear.

edit:
I could select one of the files, retrieve the full path to the file and then remove the file name, but that seems not very efficient to me.

Comment: What is the problem, adding a form, processing the form, etc.?

Comment: @ jeroen I don't really know how to solve this programand what to use in order to achieve this. At the moment, I already have a running html form asking for details about the files, like project name etc. I also know the code to select one file and upload it. However, I need to select a folder containing a bunch of files.

Comment: You should try to narrow you problem down and post the code you have already concerning that problem.

Comment: Is the question "How can a web page have a user select a local directory whose path is to be submitted by a form?" I don't think that's possible without requesting addition privileges from the user. It shouldn't be.

Comment: Information about the local file system is private. It should not be accessible by untrusted code.

Comment: Well, I mean not local on the user's computer, but local on the same server as the website and scripts. And it's only to be used as intranet in our company, so no untrusted users.

Comment: That's easy, then. When you generate the HTML, include `<input type="hidden" name="path" value="...[ the path ]...">` in the form

Comment: Re "no untrusted users", I was talking about untrusted *code* (from the servers). All servers and code from them is unstrusted until the client makes an exception (intranet or otherwise).

Comment: Then how can the user select the path?

Comment: So you want to user pick a path from the file system of another machine. Furtunately, that machine is the source of a web page the user is visiting. You will need to provide the possible paths to the user. You will need to write a means for the user to pick the paths. The simplest approach is a SELECT element. Something fancier would require someone with more skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows

One of the server-admins will put the data in a certain folder on the server, say `path/to/data/a_project_name`.

When submitting the project using a form, I include a hidden input-field containing `path/to/data/`, because all projects will be placed here. The user has to submit the name of the project, which has to be a complete match with `a_folder_name`.

Then I merge these two in one variable. This variable can then be used as argument for the Perl-script.

Kudos to ikegami!

Comment: While this solution does satisfy the needs of your project, it is still not the answer for the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to user pick a path from the file system of another machine. Fortunately, that machine is the source of a web page the user is visiting.

You will need to provide the possible paths to the user. You will need to write a means for the user to pick the paths.

The simplest approach is to generate a form with SELECT element containing the possible paths as options.

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
   <select name="path">
      <option>path1
      <option>path2
      <option>path3
      <option>path4
      ...
   </select>
</form>
```

If you feel adventurous, it's possible to create a nice hierarchical picker using "dynamic HTML" -- you could even use AJAX so the whole tree doesn't have to be sent to the client at once -- but there's isn't anything of the kind built in.